# Android App Product Link Does Not Indicate an Update is Available

Tags: android

I have an Android app which when started checks if the update is available. This is done by web service and comparing version numbers. When the server version > app version then I use the following format to transfer the user to the Google Play Store:

```
market://details?id=<package_name>
```

Strangely, when I visit the above link the Google Play Store gives me two opens "Open" OR "Uninstall". It does not give me any update link. The version Name in the app is 1.3 as indicated below:

```
android:versionName="1.3" >
```

And on the server it is

```
android:versionName="1.4" >
```

Comment: Was it just recently updated? Maybe it takes a while for the update to roll out to all servers, and your app is connecting to a different server than the Play Store app is.

Comment: The Google Play Store version was updated 2-3 weeks ago. But the app that I am testing is using the debugging keystore file. Can that be the reason that it does not see the update option.

Comment: That sounds possible. I've only tried going in the other direction...installing a debug keyed version over a release keyed version doesn't work. I would have assumed Google Play only compares package names, and you wouldn't see a problem until you got to the installer, but maybe it does really compare signs as well.